# How to add texts messages to exceptions defined by local classes?

Tags: class, exception, local, abap

I want to raise an exception of a local type, and pass it in the constructor a *text.

This *text is what i want to be returned by calling the get_longtext method, later, when i catch the exception.

Of course i can add an attribute to my class, and redefine the method. It seems to me like there should however be an easier way (like there is in the java-like languages, where you just "have" that).

There's the TEXTID parameter in the inherited constructor for the exceptions. That however points to the "texts" defined as class properties... but that's for global classes.

So is there any way for me to make use of the already existing constructor in an elegant way? 
Or must I simply do it all by hand?

Comment: Do you have a chance of using a global exception class? In this case the SE24 will handle all this stuff automatically and provide you with a nice UI to edit the texts.

Comment: yes, i *can* use global classes, but that's the last option. I went with redefining the method. I'm kinna testing the limits of what ABAP can do, to get used to it. Thx for your answers and continuous feedback.

Comment: Usually, using local classes would be the last option. You'll deprive yourself of most of the available tools if you restrict yourself to local classes. It's like testing the limits of Java using only EDLIN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to uses global classes (as recommended), you can try to implement the interface `IF_T100_MESSAGE` in your local class. First maintain the error messages in any message class via `SE91`, then define text ids in your local exception class of type `SCX_T100KEY`. Implement the exception class methods to use additional attributes for the placeholders in your message texts (if necessary).

Check `IF_T100_MESSAGE` and `CL_MESSAGE_HELPER` for details. To get example code, create a global exception class and add the interface `IF_T100_MESSAGE` and check how the methods are implemented.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to define your own local exception class which will have all the benefits of the `IF_T100_MESSAGE` interface.

If you are interested in sample code, please see my blog article (the code is quite long to be put here) at [http://oprsteny.com/?p=1346](https://web.archive.org/web/20201014043827/http://oprsteny.com/?p=1346)